# Get row values of different Ids in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I made a filtering of certain ids on an xlsx file. Transformed them to a dataframe.
The total of ids is 3.
where Id1 (in the xlsx file) have 5 row values
      Id2 have 3 row values 
      ID3 have 19 row values

In a first step I extracted just a row value for each Id (row value is time in my case in %H:%M:%S.%f and it's unique for each Id).

My dataframe looks this way :

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame([['Id1','01:22:52.134'],['Id2','03:21:31.123'],  ['Id1','21:12:52.544'],['Id3','23:12:31.216'],['Id1','10:22:02.134'],['Id2','06:52:48.184'], ['Id3','12:52:46.188'], ['Id3','06:52:46.184'], ['Id1','13:33:46.235'], ['Id2','14:35:12.235'], ['Id3','14:59:12.177']], columns=["Ids",'Time'])
```

**My request is :** 
I want to extract the row values for my selected Ids but not all row values.
e.g : - 1 row value for Id1 (initially contains 5)
      - 2 row values for Id2 (initially contains 3)
      - 17 row values for Id3 (initially contains 19)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend doing this with a `groupby` + `pd.concat`. First, you'll need a mapping:

```
mapping = {'Id1' : 1, 'Id2' : 2, 'Id3' : 17}
```

Now, use `mapping` to fetch only your desired number of rows with `GroupBy.head`:

```
pd.concat(
    [g.head(mapping[k]) for k, g in df.groupby('Ids')], axis=0
)

    Ids          Time
0   Id1  01:22:52.134
1   Id2  03:21:31.123
5   Id2  06:52:48.184
3   Id3  23:12:31.216
6   Id3  12:52:46.188
7   Id3  06:52:46.184
10  Id3  14:59:12.177
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
ids = {'Id1':1, 'Id2':2, 'Id3':17}
df = df.groupby('Ids', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.head(ids[x.name]))
print (df)
   Ids          Time
0  Id1  01:22:52.134
1  Id2  03:21:31.123
2  Id2  06:52:48.184
3  Id3  23:12:31.216
4  Id3  12:52:46.188
5  Id3  06:52:46.184
6  Id3  14:59:12.177
```

**Explanation**:

1. First create dictionary for mapping
2. Last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and for each filtered group use [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) with mapped value by dictionary

Comment: I don't know if you get well my question, but this was my try. 

`def extractfeatures(sh):
    vals = sh.row_values
    for r in range(sh.nrows):
        while vals(r,0)[1] in TimeList:
            if vals(r,0)[0] == 'id1':
                col1 = vals(r,0)[3]
            if vals(r,0)[0] == 'id2':
                col2 = [vals(r,0)[3], vals(r,0)[4]]
            if vals(r,0)[0] =='':
                col3 = [vals(r,0)[i] for i in range (3,19)]
    data= [col1, col2, col3]            
    
    return data`